# BindingResult does not show any errors when there is an error

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am using annotation based validation for one of my forms and I am not able to show any errors using the **form:errors tag** I used in JSP file. When I try to debug it, I found out that the BindingResult does not show any errors as well but I am leaving the textbox empty to test the validation. Any pointers are greatly appreciated why I am not able to validate it.

Below is my Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class RequestController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestform", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView request() {
return new ModelAndView("requestform", "command", new RequestForm());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/showResponse", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showResponse(@ModelAttribute("berequest") @Valid RequestForm berequest, BindingResult errors,
    ModelMap model) {

if (errors.hasErrors()) {
    return "requestform";
} else {


StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder()
            .append("http://" + berequest.getMachineName() + ":" + berequest.getPortNumber()
                + "/service/Service/v1/get/").append("USERID=" + berequest.getUserId())
            .append(",")
            .append("debugflag=" + berequest.isDebugFlag()).append("/")
            .append(berequest.getAttributeNames());

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url.toString(), String.class);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Object json = mapper.readValue(result, Object.class);
    String indented = mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(json);

    model.addAttribute("response", (indented));

    return "resultform";
    }
}
```

Below is my model class-

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class RequestForm {

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@NotEmpty
private String userId;

.....
}
```

Below is my requestform.jsp file

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Details:</legend>
            <form:label path="userId" for="input-one" class="float"><strong>User Id:</strong></form:label><br />
            <form:input path="userId" class="inp-text" name="input-one-name" id="input-one" type="text" size="100" />
            <form:errors path="userId" cssClass="error"/><br />

    </fieldset>
```

Below is my context.xml file

```
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!--  Allow proxys -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
            <mvc:message-converters>
              <!--  Support AJAX processing with progressive rendering. Overrides HttpOutputMessage with RaptorResponseWriter -->
            <beans:bean class="com.host.kernel.filter.RaptorJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>                  
            </mvc:message-converters>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.host.config" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.host.app.raptor.controller" />        

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests by efficiently serving up static resources 
         in the corresponding directory -->
    <resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Are you having a validator bean or `mvc:annotation-driven` tag on your configuration? ([Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html))

Comment: Updated the question with context.xml file. I am using mvc:annotation driven tag I guess.

Comment: Updated the question as well. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: there are two `mvc:annotation-driven` configurations in the xml why is it? Remove the second one. Do you have a validator framework like Hibernate Validator (http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) in your classpath

Comment: Yeah I already have removed that one but still it's not working. How can I check whether I have a validator framework like Hibernate Validator in my classpath? I added these two yesteday in my pom.xml file-   `  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
   <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>`. Will that be it?

Comment: Updated the question slightly again. That might can help you in answering my question? Do you know what might be the reason of not working?

Comment: It looks like a spring configuration issue. let me check again

Comment: In your controller can you do something like `Map<String, Validator> list = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(org.springframework.validation.Validator.class);` and see how many beans are returned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23403/discussion-between-techgeeky-and-arun-p-johny)

Comment: I got zero beans returned. More details I have provided in chat.